# Can I use CocoaPods when creating a Cocoa Touch Framework?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa, cocoapods, cocoa-touch

I'm creating a new Cocoa Touch Framework (MyFramework.framework), which will have a dependency on Alamofire. This framework will be written in Swift. As a test I started a new Cocoa Touch Framework project:

```
File > New > Project > Framework & Library > Cocoa Touch Framework
```

Then, in the terminal I performed:

```
pod init
```

under this projects directory. In the newly created Podfile I added the following:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '8.0'
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
use_frameworks!

pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.0'
```

Once again, in the Terminal I performed:

```
pod install
```

and started coding away.

Everything seemed well and good till I used the MyFramework.framework Product in a Single View Project. When I attempt to run the project I get the following issue:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire
Referenced from: /Users/me/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/87DA70B6-49BF-441E-BD81-F4A80B0792CF/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/2E414EA8-7E54-4D71-9295-566D4FAAADE2/test.app/Frameworks/MyFramework.framework/MyFramework
Reason: image not found
```

I thought that Cocoa Touch Framework projects were inherently Dynamic, and therefore would include all dependencies.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening and how I may be able to fix it? 
Is this an issue with CocoaPods or am I missing something?

I'm a noob to Stack Overflow so please let me know if you need more information from me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Unfortunately CocoaPods doesn't support use with Cocoa Touch Framework target. I found a few references to this while digging through their issues on GitHub:

> We don't really support integrating Pods into framework targets...
>   -[neonichu](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4493#issuecomment-153681304) on Nov 4, 2015

and

> ...in order for this to "just work", CP would need to do a recursive analysis of dependencies in your Xcode project and also somehow ensure that you would never use the build product in another context.
>   -[neonichu](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3440#issuecomment-119342221) on Jul 7, 2015

So far I've found two ways to deal with the issue:

**The right way** is to create a new pod spec for your framework and bring it in to your main project via CocoaPods. This resolves all of the problems CococaPods has with the dependency graph and is the recommended solution from the CocoaPods developers.

**The easy way** is to include the pods from your framework in your main project. This seems to work, but frankly I don't know why. This is the Podfile from my test project:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!

def myfirstframework_pods
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.0'
end

target 'MyApp' do
    pod 'SwiftKeychainWrapper', '~>1.0'
    myfirstframework_pods
end

target 'MyFirstFramework' do
    myfirstframework_pods
end
```

Comment: The reason why this works is that the framework you are buidling is happy  as long is its dependencies are embedded in the app (just link them, and they are embedded by the app). Apple seems to very picky about including frameworks - the only place where they should be added is in the app. This is to avoid many different frameworks adding different versions of frameworks which could cause havoc. I need only mention "java classpath" to give a picture of the other extreme. So yes, using frameworks in frameworks is very difficult, but can be done using so-called umbrella headers.

Comment: The "easy way" will give you an "[!] The 'Pods-MyApp' target has frameworks with conflicting names: googletoolboxformac" for certain libraries, such as Firebase.

Comment: Very helpful post!

Comment: The easy way works! Only took a few hours to figure out the linker error caused by what I assume were leftover link flags in the main projects build settings from previously not having `use_frameworks`.

Comment: @Dalla Edwards can you describe the right way in detail?

Comment: For **the right way**, the answer below by _humblePilgrim_ gives a good reference.

Comment: The right way -unfortunately- fails when your framework uses static library pods like Firebase ones. You should either go for second way or remove *use_frameworks!* line which makes everything worse.

Comment: So, I am trying to do something similar. Basically I now created an empty **Cocoa Touch Framework** that imports some CocoaPods. This seems to work well. But when I use the framework in a project, I cannot access public functions from CocoaPods that were imported in the framework. Any idea how that could be done?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the dependency on Alamofire in the framework's podspec as below

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|

# Other setup 

# Dependencies
s.dependency "Alamofire"
# Other dependencies if any
```

Comment: I have tried this but it seems when you install pod for your custom framework in a sample project, it gives error. For me It is showing "No such module Firebase" in my custom framework file.

Comment: Any changes in build settings which I have to do for this?

Comment: I have not used Firebase in the above manner. It did work for other pods such as  FBSDKCoreKit, FBSDKShareKit, Alamofire.

Comment: I hope you already have specified the Firebase pod in the frameworks Podfile. Else it wont build.

Comment: Yes. I have added FirebaseCore in pod file of my custom framework. But when I try to import firebase it throws an error.

Comment: Hmm. I have not used Firebase in the SDK code yet. So I am not sure what is going wrong for you :(

Comment: @PriyankaMistry The right way -unfortunately- fails when your framework uses static library pods like Firebase ones. You should either go for second way or remove use_frameworks! line which makes everything worse.