# Framework target, App target and cocoaPods working together, how to maintain dependencies

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, cocoa-touch

I am creating a framework that uses third party frameworks like alamofire. I have created a App that uses this framework and also uses third party framework again like alamofire(both could use it). So now I have 2 targets, I added both in workspace, I did pod init but it could only link with only one .xcodeproj and create its own workspace.

I also tried

[Can I use CocoaPods when creating a Cocoa Touch Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35927109/can-i-use-cocoapods-when-creating-a-cocoa-touch-framework)

but pod install didn't work as it was not able to find target and if dragged in same folder it ask to specify target path as it only want one .xcodeproj

Please if somebody could help me with this. How to access cocoa pods framework in both custom framework and app.

Answer (score -1):

Ideally the Pod should be in your App.

Even though your Framework is also using the same third party framework the pod install should be done for that at App level and both App and framework should be able to read it.
Have said that, if you are developing Framework independently you can install POD at that time in framework but when your are using this framework in app then the third party framework can be installed at app level and frameworks should also be able to read it since they are now also part of same App target.