# Creating Framework Project - Cocoatouch Framework

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, swift3, cocoapods

We are going to create a Cocoatouch framework, which has dependency of other 3rd party libraries (For Example : Alamofire , Reachability). What is the best way to create my own Cocoatouch frame work which internally using other 3rd party libraries. The framework which we are creating is a Dynamic framework and using swift language.

Please suggest which of the following is better approach.

1. Linking other frameworks (Alamofire) , inside my framework
2. Using cocoapods in my cocoatouch framework to link other third party libraries

Please provide any suggestions.

I'm new to this framework development. Usually what's the best way to create cocoatouch frameworks that depend on other libraries.[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35927109/can-i-use-cocoapods-when-creating-a-cocoa-touch-framework I think this solves your problem