# Thread 1: signal SIGABRT in Reachability framework in custom framework Swift

Tags: swift

I have developed a custom framework and I have used "Reachability" framework imported using "Carthage".

When I import my custom framework into my app project, it builds with no issues but the app crashes when it is being used. It happens the custom framework tries to initialised or when it calls any of the static variables.

Any ideas?

**Edited**:
The crash occurs when inside my custom framework I execute:

```
 private override init() {

    reachability = Reachability()

 }
```

called from my app:

```
let ohObject = OpenHomeObject.shared
```

The Carthage dependencies of my custom framework are setup accordingly to the documentation.

The crash log shows:

```
dyld`__abort_with_payload:
    0x104a4e2f0 <+0>:  mov    x16, #0x209
    0x104a4e2f4 <+4>:  svc    #0x80
->  0x104a4e2f8 <+8>:  b.lo   0x104a4e310               ; <+32>
    0x104a4e2fc <+12>: stp    x29, x30, [sp, #-0x10]!
    0x104a4e300 <+16>: mov    x29, sp
    0x104a4e304 <+20>: bl     0x104a4d990               ; cerror_nocancel
    0x104a4e308 <+24>: mov    sp, x29
    0x104a4e30c <+28>: ldp    x29, x30, [sp], #0x10
    0x104a4e310 <+32>: ret
```

Comment: Please add your crash log to the question, and the code that’s failing

Comment: please see updated question.

Comment: Have you tried just adding the `Reachability.swift` file directly (without using Carthage)?

Comment: I haven't but since I am also using other libs like "SWXMLHash.framework", which also crashes, I decided to use dependency manager.

Comment: It seems that using cocoapods inside a "cocoa touch framework" is not supported... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35927109/can-i-use-cocoapods-when-creating-a-cocoa-touch-framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally resolved the issue. I have finally used Carthage and the answer from [This Question (Also mine)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52245882/ios-dependency-manager-in-cocoa-touch-framework/52254883#52254883) solves the fully integration