# iOS Dependency manager in Cocoa Touch Framework

Tags: ios, swift, ios-frameworks, carthage

I have been researching a while and with no success on how I can build a cocoa touch framework, add dependency manger for 3rd party libraries and finally add the framework in an app project.

First, I would like to say that the framework I am planning to work with will be developed and tested while I write the app, it will be a git submodule of the main git project and.

Ideally, The structure of my the whole project looks like that

Finder:
[image]

Project

[image]

**Is that a good way to work?**

Secondly, the main issue I am facing is how to add dependency manager in my framework

I have tried "Carthage" and "Cocoapods"

With **Carthage** The main project crashes as It can't find the frameworks and with "Cocoapods", because it creates a workspaces, I can't import the the framework or, at least, I don't know how to do it.

Does anyone know a way for integrating dependency manager in a cocoa touch framework with no app project configuration?

Thank you.

Removed edited part due unfair downvotes

Comment: Why down voted? Could you add an explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Open to edit and suggestions! To be continued when Swift Package Manager is released for iOS**

**Also, I want to apologise if something is not quite right.**

ANSWER:

After a while trying different ways and methods and with drekka answer, I have figured out how to use Carthage as a dependency manager for my cocoa touch framework.

My Framework has all the Carthage files and folders, includes the Frameworks but it doesn't have the run script.

[image]

Because my framework contains public variables that depends on the frameworks imported, when I use them in App project Xcode can find them.

[image]

So in my App target "TheApp - General - Linked frameworks and libraries" i drag an drop the carthage framework reference:

[image]

And, indeed, the location is added into "TheApp - Build settings - Search path - Framework search path"

[image]

At this point the app compiles an runs in a simulator but crashes when runs in a real device as it is shown in the question. For solving this issue I add the Carthage scrips in "TheApp - Build phases"

[image]

And job done!

I was expecting an easier integration like the one you get with gradle in android but, by now, I think this is the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

Carthage is my favourite manager so I can speak to that more than Cocoapods.

When you are building a framework you want to link against any dependency managed by Carthage, but NOT include them in the framework. This is relatively simple to do. Just goto your framework target and add the Carthage built frameworks from `<project-dir>/Carthage/Build/<platform>`. The Carthage directory should end up in you frameworks search path as well.

In your main app project you need to do the same thing, ie. add the frames from the Carthage build directories and make sure that directories in the framework search path as well.

Then you need to do one extra step. You need to add a run script phases and tell it to execute `carthage copy-frameworks` and then add each of the Carthage built framework files to that phase. The reason for this is the way Apple builds frameworks requires some extra work before they are copied into your application's bundle.

I suspect the reason for your crash where it could not find the frame was that this phase was not added to your app target. So when the app ran it was not able to find the framework.

Comment: So, do you mean re-adding the frameworks and Carthage scripts in my App project? If you see my edited answer, I have been able to add the frameworks in my framework (framework search path too), add the frameworks into "Embed Binaries" and don't include any of the Carthage scripts. Is that ok?

Comment: It looks like you almost have it right. With copy-frameworks you only need to specify the input file. copy-frameworks will automatically write the adjusted framework to the correct frameworks directory in your app. You shouldn't need to do any Code signing or other stuff. Your second answer is correct. I know it seems to be difficult, but Carthage is actually very simple in that it doesn't mess with your project (which is why I like it).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Carthage is less messy. Your answer made finally got a possible solution. I had to remove all the edited part because people were down voting...